# C# how to have multiple constraints on the same type

Tags: c#, generics, idisposable

I was identified a pattern of using `IDisposable` and would like to write the following code to generise it:

```
public static void SetTo<T>(this T value, ref T pos) where T : IDisposable
{
    using (var _ = Interlocked.Exchange(ref pos, value))
    {
    }
}
```

However this didn't compile, nor can I do

```
public static void SetTo<T>(this T value, ref T pos) where T : IDisposable where T : class
{
    using (var _ = Interlocked.Exchange(ref pos, value))
    {
    }
}
```

Actually I only use this when T is a class (not value type), but `IDisposable` supports value type as well so the class constraint is not enough.

How can I specify both `IDisposable` and `class` constraint?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answer. I have also updated the title. There are suggestion that I shall check that `pos` and `value` are not the samething. Such a check can be done as following:

```
public static void SetTo<T>(this T value, ref T pos) where T : class,  IDisposable
{
    for (;;)
    {
        var old = pos;
        if (ReferenceEquals(value, old))
            return;
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref pos, value, old) != old) 
            continue;
        using (old)
           return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `where T : class, IDisposable` ?

Comment: `Interlocked.Exchange` does not return an `IDisposable`. What are you trying to do, exactly? Which pattern did you identify regarding the usage of `Interlocked.Exchange`?

Comment: @Groo When he constraint it to `IDisposable`, then `Interlocked.Exchange` would return `IDisposable` :)

Comment: @Sriram: oh, right, the generic overload. :) Didn't think of that. :)

Comment: @Earth: I'd also make sure that `value` and `pos` are never the same instance, otherwise you might end up disposing the target value also. Of course, it might be difficult to do that and preserve atomicity. If I might add, this is a pretty unconventional approach.

Comment: Am I getting this clear - you are trying to swap two values in their places twice - first time at the enter of a `using` block and the last time at the exit?

Comment: @Groo I know this. In pratice this is not a problem. The `pos` variable are usually reference counted in my case and disposing it twice is not a problem providing that `value` hold its own reference count. On the other hand, the atomicity is critical.

Comment: @Earth: but it's rather strange that you need to implement reference counting and such strange constructs in C# (or .NET). Often, when such strange patterns are used, it indicates that there might be a better (more idiomatic, or simpler, or less error prone) way to do the same thing. And I am still not sure what happens if `value` and `pos` are referencing the same instance, and you call the code simultaneously from two different threads?

Comment: @Groo You are right for there will be better way to do the things. However, my problem is that it is an existing system and it was written badly such that the resources (unmanaged) are not managed very well and causes issues. I need to adjust the code so I can track the actual resource usage.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then. If you are hunting leaks, however, a great way to find them would be using [windbg/SoS](http://humblecoder.co.uk/blog/2009/12/17/spotting-a-memory-leak-with-windbg-in-net/), if you aren't yet familiar with it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify multiple constraints followed by `,`. Just like the following

```
public static void SetTo<T>(T value, ref T pos) where T : class, IDisposable
```

For some reason compiler prevents you from doing `IDisposable, class` complaining that `class` constraint should come before all others, so you need `where T : class, IDisposable`. Ordering matters..